# A single data structure for reading in arbitrary type variables from a script, for retrieval and editing at runtime

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, scripting

I want to store arbitrary parameter data for some robotics software.  I'll give some examples to clarify what I want to do:

Say, for example, I want to store variables "quadruped.gait.step_height = 0.25" and "quadruped.gait.gait_type = "trot"" this should break down to something like

```cpp
variable_map["quadruped"]["gait"]["step_height"] = 0.25;
```

or

```cpp
variable_map["quadruped"]["gait"]["gait_type"] = "trot";
```

The code I currently have to handle this kind of thing (which works just fine if I know what the type of the variable is):

```cpp
std::map<std::string, void* > var_map;

template <class X>
void set_variable(std::string key, X var)
{
   var_map[key] = &var;
}

template <class X>
X get_variable(std::string key)
{
   return *reinterpret_cast<X*>(var_map[key]);
}
```

this does the somewhat less clean looking task of storing each variable in:

```cpp
variable_map["quadruped.gait.step_height"] = 0.25;
```

Which feels like a shoddy way of doing what I want.   And I need to know the type of the variable ahead of time:

```cpp
set_variable<bool>("quadruped.PID.workspace.active",true);
bool workspace_active = get_variable<bool>("quadruped.PID.workspace.active");
```

Ideally I'd like to handle this type of variable assignment in an XML reader or some kind of script-parsing format at startup.

I feel like this is a common need among software developers and I can't help but feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel on this problem.  Is there a piece of open source code out there (preferably with a good license), or maybe just a simpler way of reading in a script:

```
quadruped.gait.gait_timing = [ 0 0.5 0 0.5 ]
quadruped.gait.step_height = 0.25
quadruped.gait.gait_type = "trot"
quadruped.PID.workspace.active = 1
```

and storing them as:

```cpp
variable_map["quadruped"]["gait"]["gait_timing"] = (std::vector) % containing [ 0 0.5 0 0.5 ]
variable_map["quadruped"]["gait"]["step_height"] = (double) 0.25;
variable_map["quadruped"]["gait"]["gait_type"] = (std::string) "trot";
variable_map["quadruped"]["PID"]["workspace"]["active"] = (int) 1;
```

or maybe just storing them in any manner where I can retrieve them by name in my code such as in my previous example:

```cpp
bool workspace_active = get_variable<bool>("quadruped.PID.workspace.active");
```

Thanks for your help.  If you need any further clarification on any of the points I've made, I'll be monitoring this question closely.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is indeed a common problem.  Therefore there exist a common solution, which is [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) that stores a variable of an arbitrary type.

The advantage is that it constructs the variant type based on all the potential types you consider (and provide as template parameters):

```
typedef boost::variant< int, std::string, double> vtype;
```

This approach permits to avoid common issues, like the nasty misaligned variables (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414092/variant-type-storage-and-alignment-issues)).  It also enables some compile-time type checking, making sure that you don't use it accidentally types that are not foreseen.

```
vtype v1, v2; 
v1 = "Hello"; 
v2 = 0.25; 
cout << v1 << v2;
```

If you know the type stored in an object, you can get it very easily:  instead of  the risky `*reinterpret_cast<X*>` you would do:  `boost::get<X>()`

And boost offers a visitation mecanism, to provide in an elegant manner the adequate type dependent code that it has to use for processing a variant objet.  You'll find some nice examples in the link at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree.html), it implements the "hierarchical" map and also parsers to read configuration from files in some common formats. It stores the values by default in std::string format, but uses `boost::lexical_cast` to support setting and getting them in other types. If you want, you can use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) to store the values, but that would lose some parsing functionality.